# Java FIFO queue implementation

Tags: java, queue

Does anyone know if there a FIFO queue implementation in Java, or any other library which lets users set a maximum size, and automatically rejects any requests when the queue if full?

I've had a look at guava queue implementation, but from what I've seen it will remove the first element in the queue when it is full, rather than rejecting the request.

Comment: [BlockingQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html)

Comment: Which Guava queue implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the built in queues do this.  I suggest ArrayBlockingQueue as this is a natural fit for a limited size, but you can use LinkedBlockingQueue as well.  The BlockingDeque(s) support a limit as well.

BTW If you are using a queue with a thread I suggest you use an ExecutorService as it combines these in one.

Comment: I've had a look at ArrayBlockingQueue, but I can't seem to find any way to set the size. Do you know where I could find this?

Comment: There is no way to create an ArrayBlockingQueue without giving it a capacity.  Just try creating one.

Answer (score 0):

Use a decorator pattern over a simple queue such as:
`Queue<String> queue = new LinkedList<String>();`

Your wrapper code will make sure the max size is forced rejecting extra additions.

Answer (score 0):

```
int size=500;
Queue<String> = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(size);
```